# Creating a random generated array in method and printing it

Tags: java, class, methods

So I'm pretty sure I've correctly created a random integer generator that will put the integers into an array, although I am having trouble with my second method, that is supposed to print out the array.

My code:

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Engine {

public int numDigits, numDigitsSet;
public int i;
public int[] secretNumber;
public Random randomNumberGenerator;



Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void setNumDigits()
{

    numDigitsSet = numDigits;

}

public int getNumDigits()
{
    System.out.print("Enter the number of digits to use: ");
    return numDigits = sc.nextInt();

}

public void generateNewSecret()
{
Random rand = new Random();{
for (int i=0; i<numDigitsSet; i++)
{
    secretNumber[i]= rand.nextInt(10);
    System.out.println("" + secretNumber[i]);

        }
    }
}

public int[] getSecretNumber()
{
     for (int j=0; j<secretNumber.length; j++)
     {
         System.out.println("" + secretNumber[j]);
     }
    return secretNumber;
}


public void convertNumtoDigitArray()
{
    String[] userGuessSplit = Player.userGuess.split(",");
    int[] userGuessArray = new int[userGuessSplit.length];
    for (int j=0; j<userGuessSplit.length; j++)
    {
        userGuessArray[j] = Integer.parseInt(userGuessSplit[j]);
    }


}







}
```

Comment: Please show us the rest of the class. Particularly where secretNumber is defined and allocated.

Comment: We'll need to see the entire class. It's the `secretNumber` variable that is null, but the reason could be any number of things.

Comment: @Jason Sorry, Edited!

Comment: You need to create the secretNumber array somewhere - until you do, it will be null.

Comment: @Jason Didn't I create it in the generateNewSecret method, the line that is giving it a rand.nextInt ??

Comment: @Nadal nope, you're still attempting to use a null object there too. Since it is an instance variable of the class you showed us, that array should be set up in the constructor, or maybe at the top of the `generateNewSecret` method.

Answer (score 0):

For printing out the array, you can use the seriously convenient

```
Arrays.toString(array);
```

JavaDoc: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29)